# Regex to match everything inside brackets ignore nested

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am looking for a regex rule to match everything inside square brackets, including the brackets and ignoring the possible brackets inside. E.g. from:

```
[value] in the [text[42]] and [1[2[3]]]!
```

I need to extract `[value]`, `[text[42]]` and `[1[2[3]]]`.

I use

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Here are more expamples - https://regex101.com/r/Xp4ghi/1

P.S. I am going to use it in .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\[(?>[^][]+|(?<c>)\[|(?<-c>)])+]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xp4ghi/4). *Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?>[^][]+|(?<c>)\[|(?<-c>)])+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `[^][]+|` - one or more chars other than `]` and `[`, or
  - `(?<c>)\[|` - a `[` char and a value is pushed onto Group "c" stack, or
  - `(?<-c>)]` - a `]` char and a value is popped off the Group "c" stack
- `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Note that .Net seems to be the only regex engine that supports this -- none of the other on regex101.com do, and neither `sed -E` nor `perl -pe` allow it.

Comment: @cfstras Yes, balancing constructs are only supported by .NET regex. You can do a lot of similar things with recursion in Perl, PCRE, Boost and Onigmo regex flavors.

Comment: Do you have an example that could work with `perl -pe`?

Comment: @cfstras It is common knowledge, `\[(?:[^][]++|(?R))*]`

Comment: Nice, thanks. For anybody who came here searching how to remove nested XML tags or C++ template arguments from a string, this can filter them out, along with their contents:
`perl -pe 's/<(?:[^<>]++|(?R))*>//g'`

Comment: And if the file is UTF8 encoded, `perl -CSD -pe 's/<(?:[^<>]++|(?R))*>//g' file > newfile`. Or inline: ```perl -i -CSD -pe 's/<(?:[^<>]++|(?R))*>//g' file```.