# I need to extract the config block as Python dict

Tags: python, regex, dataform

I have a dataform project and I need to extract the config block of .sqlx files and parse it as Python dictionary.

I am trying using RegEx.

RegEx: `config\s*{[^}]*}`

```py
import re

config_pattern = r'config\s*{[^}]*}'
config_match = re.search(config_pattern, sql_content, re.DOTALL)

if config_match:
    config_block = config_match.group(0)
    print(config_block)
else:
    print("Config block not found.")
```

**Input:**

```sql
config {
    type:"table",
    schema:"xt_pto",
    name:"xt_daily_pto",
    bigquery:{
        partitionBy:"BKDate"
    },
    tags:[
        "xt_daily_pto",
        "budget"
    ]
}

WITH latest_date AS (
    SELECT MAX(dt) dt
    FROM ${ref('xt_daily_pto')}
)

SELECT ... -- Rest of my query
```

**Desired Output:**

```py
{
    "type":"table",
    "schema":"xt_pto",
    "name":"xt_daily_pto",
    "bigquery":{
        "partitionBy":"BKDate"
    },
    "tags":[
        "xt_daily_pto",
        "budget"
    ]
}
```

But the RegEx `config\s*{[^}]*}` is matching the first `}` of bigquery key and output is truncated:

```
{
    type:"table",
    schema:"xt_pto",
    name:"xt_daily_pto",
    bigquery:{
        partitionBy:"BKDate"
    }
```

Comment: If indentation matches depth, use e.g. [`(?ms)config\s*{(.*?)^}`](https://regex101.com/r/uZgNHS/2)

Comment: Regular expressions are not a good tool for this. Is the structure of the sqlx files consistent, e.g. is there _always_  a WITH statement immediately after the config block?

Answer (score 0):

i found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71769611/regex-to-match-everything-inside-brackets-ignore-nested) about a similar regex problem.

modifying it for curlies, to allow them to be empty and adding the “config”:

```
config \{(?>[^\}\{]+|(?<c>)\{|(?<-c>)\})*\}
```

now this will not parse as an actual python dict because there are no quotes around the names. i imagine an approach like this might work:

- use a similar regex to capture each comma seperated element, ignoring commas if they are in a pair of brackets
- split each capture group at the first “:”
- recurse on the right half with pretty much the first pattern until there are no brackets in the string
- the recursive function returns a tuple with the left string and either a dict or a string which is then inserted into the “parent” dict as a key-value-pair

unfortunately i am not very well versed in regex so i won’t try and make this for you, but i bet you can figure something out :)

Comment: Looks like the `?<c>` extension is not supported by the python `re` library. Anyway regular expressions are very much the wrong tool to use for matching nested brackets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).